# Basic Way to Open Files in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to open local xml file and output its content in terminal.

I've tried this;

```
puts File.new('file.xml', 'r')
```

and this;

```
puts File.open('file.xml', 'r')
```

output from both is, instead of printing xml file to the screen;

```
#<File:0x00000000....>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
puts File.read('file.xml')
```

or

```
puts File.open('file.xml').read
```

Documentation: [IO.read](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-read), [IO#read](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-read)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use block with `File#open` method. As with block,you don't need to close the file explicitly.Perform all your task inside the block with the file. [The file will be closed automatically](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-open),when block will be terminated.

```
File.open('doc.txt','r') do |file|
  puts file.read
end

# >> ,"11: Agriculture, Forestry, Fishing and Hunting",,
# >> ,,"111: Crop Production",
# >> ,,,"111110: Soybean Farming"
# >> ,,,"111120: Oilseed (except Soybean) Farming"
```

Comment: Thank you, but I only needed to know the simplest way to open file :-)

Comment: @Tux Yes.. But without block you have to put a line to close the file,which is not needed with block.. Now think what is simple approach.. :)